# ssh connection refused from the terminal

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a server using SSH, but I got this error:

> ssh: connect to host prh.prhgp.eve.es port 22: Connection
>   refused

I have 2 servers, one of them works but the other doesn't.

What confused me is, when I connect using putty APP it works without problem, but when I do it from the terminal I got this error. I tried also from a windows device (using cmd) and I have the same issue.

Comment: Did yo uconfirm the issue isn't remote firewall or a local firewall on your network blocking the connection?

Comment: @ThomasWard , yes .. because I can connect to the other server from my device .. and I can connect to the server "that doesn't accept the connections" from Putty app.